# How can I select rows based on a search parameter containing one of the fields in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search a table based on a string and find all rows that have a field which is within the given search string. Here is an example:

```
ID    | Permission
------+--------
1     | ADMIN
2     | MODERATOR
3     | USERS
```

Then I would search that table with a string. Example: "USER+COMMENT+MODERATOR" and I would want to find all entries with the permission field in the given search string. Thank you for your help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Which of your sample records would be returned given your `USER+COMMENT+MODERATOR` search string?

Comment: @JNevill Row 2 would be returned and row 3 would've been if the string was USERS+... instead of USER+...

Comment: @GordonLinoff fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In standard SQL, you can do:

```
where '+' || 'USER+COMMENT+MODERATOR' || '+' like '%+' || permission || '+%'
```

`||` is the ANSI standard string concatenation operator.  Some databases do not support it, preferring `+` or `CONCAT()` instead.

In MySQL, this would be:

```
where concat('+', 'USER+COMMENT+MODERATOR', '+') like concat('%+', permission, '+%')
```

Comment: isn't it better to split input string and then check if splited collection contains column value?